Using Ray and RayCast to look around in first person
I am currently working on a small project where you controll the character in first person mode, allthough this question is also relevant for third person. What I want to do is looking around by just moving the mouse over the screen, like in any kind of first person game. My problem is that with the methods I tried so far, the camerea always continues turning when the cursor is just slightly off center.
I created a method called LookWithMouse on my PlayerBehaviour script. Here the first try:
private void LookWithMouse()
{
    Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    Ray ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(mousePos);
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction);
    Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, this.transform.position);

    float distanceToPlane;

    if (plane.Raycast(ray, out distanceToPlane))
    {
        Vector3 hitPoint = ray.GetPoint(distanceToPlane);

        this.transform.LookAt(hitPoint);

        Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, hitPoint, Color.yellow);
    }
}

Here I tried casting a ray from the camera and interscting it with a plane. Besides the problem of the constantly moving camera there is the issue that it only works as long as I dont look up. because the plane is only on the floor.
Here the other try:
private void LookWithMouse()
{
    Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    Vector3 point = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, _camera.nearClipPlane));
    Vector3 direction = (_camera.transform.position - point) * -1;
    Debug.Log($"Direction: {direction}");

    int layerMask = 1 << 2;
    layerMask = ~layerMask;


    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(_camera.transform.position, direction, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(_camera.transform.position, direction * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
        Debug.Log("Did Hit");
        hitPoint = hit.point;
        Debug.Log($"Hit point: {hit.point}");
    }
    this.transform.LookAt(hitPoint);
    }

Here I cast a ray and let it collide with colliders I set up around my world. This way I can look in every direction but the camera doesnt stop moving.
Another attempt which uses the GetAxis() method. I copied this script from someone online:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
    public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
    public float sensitivityX = 15F;
    public float sensitivityY = 15F;

    public float minimumX = -360F;
    public float maximumX = 360F;

    public float minimumY = -60F;
    public float maximumY = 60F;

    float rotationY = 0F;

    void Update()
    {
        if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
        {
            float rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;

            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
        }
        else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        // Make the rigid body not change rotation
        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
    }
}


Can anyone help?

What's the reasoning behind using raycasts, instead of just rotating the camera based on how much the mouse moved in a frame? Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"); and Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");?

@ipodtouch0218
I tried that aswell with a code I got online but the problem there was that the looking around was not really smooth

If you were multiplying the result of Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"); by Time.deltaTime, that's probably why. You don't need to multiply by deltaTime for that. If you still have the code from that attempt I'd like to see it.

well, depending on how you were doing the movement, theres a good chance the reason it was odd was because you were moving by mouse position not by how much it had moved * speed or whatever, hence if not dead center it would keep moving..  The reason your camera doesnt stop moving is as its moving, the mouse gets a new target.. so lets say initially you are looking at 0,0 and click 0,100, well, so it moves to 0,100 but now the mouse is down pointing at 0,200.. so it moves...

I editet my question to include the code where I was trying to move it with the GetAxis method. I saw that there is no multiplication with Time.deltaTime. Do you maybe have another idea as to why it isnt that smooth?
@BugFinder Does Input.GetAxis(Mouse Y(or X)) return the mouse position? If so, how can I get how much it moved from it?
Thank you guys for your help!

Input.GetAxis("Mouse X/Y") returns the amount the mouse moved in that direction since the last frame, not it's absolute position.
